# logstash restrict search result to past day

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to query Elasticsearch for an index a day before current date in Logstash using Elasticsearch input plugin.

I tried the following config for logstash,

```
input { 
        elasticsearch 
        { 
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
            index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd-6}" 
            query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }' 
            size => 500 
            scroll => "5m" 
            docinfo => true 
        } 
    } 
    output { stdout { codec => rubydebug }    
}
```

Can someone help me on how to do it?

Comment: have you tried anything? can you please show us an example of what you want?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori  I tried the following config for logstash
`input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd-6}"
    query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Date math index name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html) within your elastic search query,

> Date math index name resolution enables you to search a range of
>   time-series indices, rather than searching all of your time-series
>   indices and filtering the results or maintaining aliases. Limiting the
>   number of indices that are searched reduces the load on the cluster
>   and improves execution performance. For example, if you are searching
>   for errors in your daily logs, you can use a date math name template
>   to restrict the search to the past two days.
>
> Almost all APIs that have an index parameter, support date math in the
>   index parameter value.

for instance to search for indices for yesterday, assuming the index use the default Logstash index name format, `logstash-YYYY.MM.dd`

```
GET /<logstash-{now/d-1d}>/_search
```

Comment: I tried with logstash-{now/d-1d} Still getting index not found error.
`input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash-{now/d-1d}"
    query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}`

Comment: Thanks @SufiyanGhori, 

`index => "<logstash-{now/d}>"`

Works for me.